# How to add text in option using jquery?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

in my wordpress e-commerce i have plugin that has select option inside the option i want to add text "Popular" to an existing text.

Ex: Medium Tail

Expected Output should be

Medium Tail/Popular

is there a jquery that could insert text?.

I do appreciate Your help Thank you:

Comment: this is not a very good question, you should provide code also it seems you are simply asking how to do something instead of help with an attempt. That being said, this is achievable through both WP and jquery, however, you need to somehow flag the popular items - maybe a custom field which adds a class to the title in your template. then you need to apply the additional text via jquery on document ready by listening for this class in the DOM and using the .text() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:
HTML:

```
<span id="text1">Medium Tail</span>
```

JS: you can use empty and append method to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#text1").empty().append("Medium Tail/Popular");
});
```

Plz check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/o1f77e1y/